# Decoding alphanumeric code into key values object using bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer, byte, biginteger

I have a "crosshair code" from CS:GO game: `CSGO-O4Jsi-V36wY-rTMGK-9w7qF-jQ8WB`

I can decode some values by using this function:

```
import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';

// Intentionally no 0 and 1 number in DICTIONARY
const DICTIONARY = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefhijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789';
const DICTIONARY_LENGTH = DICTIONARY.length;
const SHARECODE_PATTERN = /CSGO(-?[\w]{5}){5}$/;

function bigNumberToByteArray(big) {
  const str = big.toString(16).padStart(36, '0');
  const bytes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(str.slice(i, i + 2), 16));
  }

  return bytes;
}


function bytesToInt32(bytes) {
  let number = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    number += bytes[i];
    if (i < bytes.length - 1) {
      number = number << 8;
    }
  }

  return number;
}

const decode = shareCode => {
  if (!shareCode.match(SHARECODE_PATTERN)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid share code');
  }

  shareCode = shareCode.replace(/CSGO|-/g, '');
  const chars = Array.from(shareCode).reverse();
  let big = new BigNumber(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    big = big.multipliedBy(DICTIONARY_LENGTH).plus(DICTIONARY.indexOf(chars[i]));
  }

  const bytes = bigNumberToByteArray(big);

  return {
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: bytesToInt32(bytes.slice(4, 5).reverse()),
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: bytesToInt32(bytes.slice(5, 6).reverse()),
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: bytesToInt32(bytes.slice(6, 7).reverse())
  };
};

console.log(decode('CSGO-O4Jsi-V36wY-rTMGK-9w7qF-jQ8WB'))
// { cl_crosshaircolor_r: 50, cl_crosshaircolor_g: 250, cl_crosshaircolor_b: 84
```

I can't figure out how to get the rest of the values, because it does not show correct numbers.

I should get these values from it:

```
{
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: 0,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: 0.3,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: 0.6,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: 0.8,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: 127,
    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: 1.5,
    cl_crosshair_t: 1,
    cl_crosshairalpha: 200,
    cl_crosshaircolor: 5,
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: 84,
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: 250,
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: 50,
    cl_crosshairdot: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: 0,
    cl_crosshairsize: 33,
    cl_crosshairstyle: 2,
    cl_crosshairthickness: 4.1,
    cl_crosshairusealpha: 0,
    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: -10
}
```

**Additional examples:**

```
CSGO-tEAHu-36Ro8-Oyms7-NVvnV-F6XDJ
{
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: 0,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: 0.1,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: 0.8,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: 0.6,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: 13,
    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: 2,
    cl_crosshair_t: 0,
    cl_crosshairalpha: 250,
    cl_crosshaircolor: 5,
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: 90,
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: 255,
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: 55,
    cl_crosshairdot: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap: -2,
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: 0,
    cl_crosshairsize: 10,
    cl_crosshairstyle: 2,
    cl_crosshairthickness: 4.5,
    cl_crosshairusealpha: 1,
    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: 12
}

CSGO-rGhtd-eWuUm-EWVO7-72rvk-zqAUM
{
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: 1,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: 0.9,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: 0.5,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: 0.6,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: 12,
    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: 0.5,
    cl_crosshair_t: 0,
    cl_crosshairalpha: 189,
    cl_crosshaircolor: 2,
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: 123,
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: 229,
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: 67,
    cl_crosshairdot: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap: 3,
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: 0,
    cl_crosshairsize: 7,
    cl_crosshairstyle: 4,
    cl_crosshairthickness: 1.2,
    cl_crosshairusealpha: 0,
    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: -5
}

CSGO-wQ3FD-JiRVa-kKcFt-6XfbF-uMD7K
{
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: 1,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: 0.9,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: 0.5,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: 0.6,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: 12,
    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: 1.5,
    cl_crosshair_t: 1,
    cl_crosshairalpha: 158,
    cl_crosshaircolor: 5,
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: 198,
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: 182,
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: 91,
    cl_crosshairdot: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap: 1.4,
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: 1,
    cl_crosshairsize: 6.4,
    cl_crosshairstyle: 4,
    cl_crosshairthickness: 1.8,
    cl_crosshairusealpha: 1,
    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: -5
}
```

**Range of properties:**

```
{
    // acts like boolean
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: {
        min: 0,
        step: 0.1, // e.g: 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc.
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: {
        min: 0,
        step: 0.1, // e.g: 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc.
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: {
        min: 0.3,
        step: 0.1, // 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 etc.
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 127
        max: 127
    },
    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: {
        min: 0,
        step: 0.5, // e.g: 0, 0.5, 1, ..., 3
        max: 3
    },
    // acts like boolean
    cl_crosshair_t: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshairalpha: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 1, 2, 3, ..., 255
        max: 255
    },
    cl_crosshaircolor: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 1, 2, 3, ..., 7
        max: 7
    },
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 1, 2, 3, ..., 255
        max: 255
    },
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 1, 2, 3, ..., 255
        max: 255
    },
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 1, 2, 3, ..., 255
        max: 255
    },
    // acts like boolean
    cl_crosshairdot: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshairgap: {
        min: -12.8,
        step: 0.1, // e.g: 10, 10.1 etc.
        max: 12.7
    },
    // acts like boolean
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1
    },
    cl_crosshairsize: {
        min: 0,
        step: 0.1, // e.g: 0, 0.1, 0.2, 14.4 etc.
        max: 819.100037 // can't say why such an unusual output
    },
    cl_crosshairstyle: {
        min: 0,
        step: 1, // e.g: 1, 2, 3, ..., 7
        max: 7
    }
    cl_crosshairthickness: {
        min: 0,
        step: 0.1, // e.g: 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 6.3
        max: 6.3
    }
    // acts like boolean
    cl_crosshairusealpha: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1
    },
    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: {
        min: -12.8,
        step: 0.1, // e.g: 10, 10.1 etc.
        max: 12.7
    }
}
```

**Values changed one at a time:**

```
Default: CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN
{
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: 1,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: 0.3,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: 1,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: 0.5,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: 7,
    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: 1,
    cl_crosshair_t: 0,
    cl_crosshairalpha: 200,
    cl_crosshaircolor: 1,
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: 50,
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: 250,
    cl_crosshaircolor_r: 50,
    cl_crosshairdot: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap: 1,
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: 0,
    cl_crosshairsize: 5,
    cl_crosshairstyle: 2,
    cl_crosshairthickness: 0.5,
    cl_crosshairusealpha: 1,
    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: 3
}

The only value changed is described beside, rest stays the same as default 
above.

cl_crosshair_drawoutline
1   = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN
0   = CSGO-of9RX-KD5Fp-4kb7Q-EoVSz-cb7nM

cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio
0   = CSGO-Vtkiw-zkx82-6AYMS-9OXdk-6yXHK
0.5 = CSGO-Trqu8-WUQCn-5MfrP-KDUGF-CFeKP
1   = CSGO-QMSEL-6KJoK-vvajh-WpPKZ-Bh2ED

cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod
0   = CSGO-Tabp9-L98iF-Btmcu-64Das-MdaEC
0.5 = CSGO-HRKjJ-R5sqr-Q6t9r-GsADN-SthGH
1   = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN

cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod
0.3 = CSGO-RBqva-DumOx-WPvGy-cDxic-5zcBN
0.7 = CSGO-jNCMK-q6UXz-pA93e-FAGu4-2GzQN
1   = CSGO-DWSPa-oEJum-4Tn8R-SrTXs-jxkbN

cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist
0   = CSGO-Dxzuf-AUuea-G7enM-c3Zza-sBhrM
50  = CSGO-LcTca-Laf43-7pmXZ-jnJGu-oS9zP
127 = CSGO-xa4d4-MN8pW-aETR7-jhzeQ-6DjjD

cl_crosshair_outlinethickness
0   = CSGO-aQUWL-7ysnT-Ve8rS-PHXDY-5zcBN
1.5 = CSGO-LhmCW-jzV4T-m6T4z-SOtbU-nhPNN
3   = CSGO-5x4rh-N29JU-3VqEY-WUF3Q-VPBYN

cl_crosshair_t
0   = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN
1   = CSGO-iyOcd-YLrjN-8xQqU-xZa3G-zjRFE

cl_crosshairalpha
0   = CSGO-sQOF4-9RKDe-sLeFU-wqGMn-uonpQ
200 = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN
255 = CSGO-BqGwL-hirNt-AX6Dy-YbCoB-fFDmQ

cl_crosshaircolor
0 = CSGO-4KA8L-stYs2-aqTxt-3R3GF-KZEFN
4 = CSGO-C8ZDo-TJrEr-uafja-dOLSe-GqZUN
7 = CSGO-JxAn9-Qa5UE-AvLpN-r6X6T-yWMfN

cl_crosshaircolor_b
0   = CSGO-8fuTL-n9Uqy-iF6pY-6tOYX-brNAK
200 = CSGO-xWpEr-keTtj-QmeUw-XpE3a-FCPcF
255 = CSGO-W58Ja-mo8Q6-e7Phv-3mK2v-NJn6J

cl_crosshaircolor_g
0   = CSGO-BvDs8-JUwK4-54sLY-c745T-yWMfN
200 = CSGO-h7whC-Uiy99-WKxr3-HLJYX-brNAK
255 = CSGO-Wnbcy-QvJ47-65Eqz-MQUXs-jxkbN

cl_crosshaircolor_r
0   = CSGO-uznHJ-WZpew-rQpJS-p2F8W-brNAK
200 = CSGO-aaBpx-XNVPr-zES6H-MTdMc-FCPcF
255 = CSGO-nOKuX-kEo8c-hBOZh-WaOpx-NJn6J

cl_crosshairdot
0 = CSGO-c8tdf-txA5L-UFDY3-zuu69-i6OJM
1 = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN

cl_crosshairgap
-12.8 = CSGO-N5fyF-u3u8M-4jU9j-O9vLu-aSYbD
0     = CSGO-qis8G-DpZxE-Z9QeN-upthN-OSveM
12.7  = CSGO-XuT3W-BvVvv-cvEFo-cM8iA-CtxXD

cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue
0 = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN
1 = CSGO-zYEbz-m4Zmk-5MfrP-KDUGF-CFeKP

cl_crosshairsize
0 = CSGO-hzFpv-XtPmX-wHSxa-LvOYX-brNAK
100 = CSGO-Cn2cE-Mau97-N4rOC-typ7o-ayzpH
819 = CSGO-GC68x-Jh9L4-73R6P-zjXN8-WGSyL
819.100037 = CSGO-MjLui-qkX6J-CUzmL-Pybui-mp33L

cl_crosshairstyle
0 = CSGO-TjyO2-rj2yR-OWps8-pjocQ-asS4M
4 = CSGO-ho3st-BGGwV-y3ERW-4bPzG-VPBYN
7 = CSGO-875F5-AdfP5-QfXa5-S3qGu-vnhvN

cl_crosshairthickness
0   = CSGO-r6TO2-WsYFC-K6GCD-RVj6o-MKsyM
3.1 = CSGO-ToYxk-5EQKD-ciNhr-tn3ya-kq8vO
6.3 = CSGO-LAYaa-DEf8T-2n2tR-mKQRz-OwxwQ

cl_crosshairusealpha
0 = CSGO-GfZhN-2sjMv-t8iFe-hcMv4-Gw8GJ
1 = CSGO-6G2cS-WzcxT-fH3dp-Rf7oq-X9oJN

cl_fixedcrosshairgap
-12.80 = CSGO-OPDHV-Ab3cf-pmoFG-8ecMS-eNqRP
0      = CSGO-NJ6Z7-bRb8Y-qSBRv-cZ8Ys-7xSOG
12.70  = CSGO-SSCsS-u4nYT-rKGYL-iRYoq-QoFOP
```

Comment: your `decode` function clearly create the data wit `matchId` and `reservationId`... there is absolutely no binding from that structure to the last one. You need a completely different function... how can we help you?

Comment: I edited question @DanieleRicci, so it should be more clear now.
I changed return object, and it can decode correctly some values from "share code" so there is binding between these structures, but I can't figure out how to get the rest of it.

Comment: To provide you an answer you should provide us the the mapping from the byte stream to the data. Otherwise how can I know which byte in the byte stream should be mapped to (example) `cl_crosshairgap` property?

Comment: @DanieleRicci Isn't it possible by just checking which number equals number in object above? So for example if some bytes hold value -10 then we know it's `cl_fixedcrosshairgap` (exactly as I did with some values in example)? I know there is couple of keys with the same value "1", but at least I would know which bytes hold this information, even without knowing names exactly.

Comment: we have to extract 20 properties, many of which not integers from a 18 bytes stream. Yes it's more or less impossible with just one example. If you could provide several examples (better if with slight difference between each other) it could make the challenge possible.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I've provided more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Add this `parseBytes` function, modify `decode` as shown, and keep the rest of your code as it.

```js
function parseBytes(bytes) {
  return {
    cl_crosshairgap: Int8Array.of(bytes[2])[0] / 10.0,

    cl_crosshair_outlinethickness: (bytes[3] & 7) / 2.0,

    cl_crosshaircolor_r: bytes[4],
    cl_crosshaircolor_g: bytes[5],
    cl_crosshaircolor_b: bytes[6],
    cl_crosshairalpha: bytes[7],
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitdist: bytes[8],

    cl_fixedcrosshairgap: Int8Array.of(bytes[9])[0] / 10.0,

    cl_crosshaircolor: bytes[10] & 7,
    cl_crosshair_drawoutline: bytes[10] & 8 ? 1 : 0,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_innermod: ((bytes[10] & 0xF0) >> 4) / 10.0,

    cl_crosshair_dynamic_splitalpha_outermod: (bytes[11] & 0xF) / 10.0,
    cl_crosshair_dynamic_maxdist_splitratio: ((bytes[11] & 0xF0) >> 4) / 10.0,

    cl_crosshairthickness: (bytes[12] & 0x3F) / 10.0,

    cl_crosshairstyle: (bytes[13] & 0xE) >> 1,
    cl_crosshairdot: bytes[13] & 0x10 ? 1 : 0,
    cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue: bytes[13] & 0x20 ? 1 : 0,
    cl_crosshairusealpha: bytes[13] & 0x40 ? 1 : 0,
    cl_crosshair_t: bytes[13] & 0x80 ? 1 : 0,

    cl_crosshairsize: (((bytes[15] & 0x1f) << 8) + bytes[14]) / 10.0
  };
}

const decode = shareCode => {
  if (!shareCode.match(SHARECODE_PATTERN)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid share code');
  }

  shareCode = shareCode.replace(/CSGO|-/g, '');
  const chars = Array.from(shareCode).reverse();
  let big = new BigNumber(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    big = big.multipliedBy(DICTIONARY_LENGTH).plus(DICTIONARY.indexOf(chars[i]));
  }
  
  return parseBytes(bigNumberToByteArray(big));
}
```

Comment: If you know how to reverse decoding function and make an encoding function, it would be awesome. I made different question on SO if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63088272/3075373